# Copia de estrutura de materiais Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Possuímos a seguinte estrutura de cadastro de materiais:

Tabela

```
Pk            FK            Filial  Descricao material
```

Grupo

```
Cod_grupo               
 1             -                1   Materiais de escritório
 2             -                1   EPIS
 3             -                1   impressos
```

Subgrupo

```
Cod_Subgrupo         Cod_grupo      
        111             1               1   Acessórios para Computador
        24              2               1   Uniformes
        203             3               1   Jornais e revistas
```

Classe

```
   Cod_classe    Cod_Subgrupo       
   1028          111                1   Insumos 
   856           203                1   Jornais e revistas
   18            24                 1   Uniformes
```

Material

```
Cod_material    Cod_classe      
 313131          1028              1    Etiqueta
 313132          1028              1    Fotocondutor
 313133          856               1    Livros
 313134          856               1    Jornais
 313135          18                1    Bota
 313136          18                1    Luva
```

Com base nessa estrutura, preciso replicar a mesma estrutura para a filial 2. O problema é que as `Fks`. Como eu poderia criar um script que copiasse essa estrutura seguindo as hierarquias de `grupo --> sugrupo --> classe --Material` ?

Comment: grosso modo insert into select 2 filial , .... from tabela1 where filial = 1 . faça este sql para todas as tabelas na ordem hierárquica.

Answer (score 1):

Como não sei a estrutura da sua tabela, então implementei conforme entendimento da regra de negocio.

Não sei como está feito em seu banco para sequenciar cada PK, então fiz uma sequencia, com base no maior código da tabela:

```
DECLARE
 I  NUMBER(11);
BEGIN
 SELECT MAX(g.cod_grupo)+1
   INTO I
   FROM grupo g;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('create sequence seq_grupo start with '||I);   
END;
/
```

Então criei o `Insert`, que se baseia em uma consulta, da qual basicamente pega o próximo código, e faz um `decode` na filial, onde for 1 substitui por 2.

```
INSERT INTO grupo
  SELECT seq_grupo.nextval AS cod_grupo
        ,DECODE(g.filial,1,2) AS filial
        ,g.descricao
    FROM grupo g;
```

Teria que criar a estrutura acima, para cada tabela.

Fiz um exemplo usando o livesql da Oracle, já que o site sqlfiddle estava dando problema https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_E08Y4Z2WO3EWKV63CTNHR1SIL.html